# how to validate that image uploaded must be multiple while submitting form in laravel?

Tags: laravel

how to validate that image uploaded must be multiple while submitting form in laravel?I mean when user upload only single image,then return back.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean? The user is supposed to upload two images, which have to be identical?

Comment: you can count the elements in the array of file input https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. its hardcoded. hope it gives you insight on what to do:

```
'filename.*' => 'mimes:pdf,doc,docx,jpeg,jpg,gif,png,bmp|max:8300',

if($request->hasfile('filename'))
    {

        $i=count($request->file('filename'));
         if($i<=1){

             dd('must be multiple');
         }
         else
         {
             //dd('multiple: '.count($request->file('filename')));
             //loop and insert into db
            foreach($request->file('filename') as $file)
                {
                    $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
                    $file->move(public_path().'/attachments', $name);

                    DB::table('tblimg')->insert([

                    'filename' => $name,

                    ]);

                }
        }
    }
```